# How to check column value in multiple columns in two dataframes (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

DataFrame 1:

```
     Email            Mobile    
  0  test1@test1.com  98989892     
  1  test4@test4.com  98989895
  2  test5@test5.com  98989894 
  3  Otheruser@mail.com 98438348342343
```

DataFrame 2:

```
     Name        Email1           Email2          Email 3    
  0  x_person    test1@test1.com  hello@hello.com Hello@Hello.com    
  1  y_person    test4@test4.com                  test2@test2.com
  2  z_person.   test5@test5.com  asasas@asas.com
```

What is the best way to check Email column value of data frame 1 exist in any of email columns in data frame 2 ? if exists then i want to combine (left join) the records as matches..

Expected result:

```
 Email               Mobile                Name       Email1    
 test1@test1.com     98989892              x_person   test1@test1.com 
 test4@test4.com     98989895              y_person.  test4@test4.com  
 test5@test5.com     98989894              z_person.  test5@test5.com 
 Otheruser@mail.com  98438348342343
```

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: ```Email                          Mobile                Name         Email1
  0  test1@test1.com     98989892              x_person   test1@test1.com 
  1  test4@test4.com     98989895              y_person.  test4@test4.com
  2  test5@test5.com     98989894              z_person.  test5@test5.com
  3  Otheruser@mail.com 98438348342343 ```

Comment: Always add new information and expected results to the question, not the comments. Please [edit] and add your comment to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and left join:

```
df22 = df2.melt('Name', value_name='Email').drop('variable', axis=1)
df = df1.merge(df22, on='Email', how='left')
print (df)
                Email          Mobile      Name
0     test1@test1.com        98989892  x_person
1     test4@test4.com        98989895  y_person
2     test5@test5.com        98989894  z_person
3  Otheruser@mail.com  98438348342343       NaN
```

Comment: Email value of data frame 1 may exist in on any of three email columns in dataframe 2. How do i left join in this case?

Comment: @SatheeshNarayanan - For this reason there is used melt.